# GeoJson object (layer) not being added to Folium map

Tags: python, here-api, folium

Have looked at previous similar questions and implemented suggestions but I am still having trouble getting a layer to appear on a Folium map. Basically I have used Here's isoline API to create an array of GeoJson data objects (these are bascially areas reacjable within certain drivetimes). I can render these drivetimes on a Here map but would like to use Folium as I think it's easier to set layer colors etc.

So the GeoJson objects (drivetimes) are stored in an array called "values".

My code is as follows:

```
# Create the map
m = folium.Map(location=[latitude, longitude], zoom_start=13)

# Add a marker to the map
folium.Marker(
    [latitude, longitude]
).add_to(m)

# Add the layer
folium.GeoJson(data=value[0], name="geojson").add_to(m)
folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)

m
```

An example of one of the drivetimes is as follows, any help would be appreciated:

```
{"data": {"features": [{"geometry": {"coordinates": [[[-6.643639, 53.382568], [-6.635742, 53.382568], [-6.633682, 53.381882], [-6.632309, 53.380508], [-6.630249, 53.379822], [-6.622009, 53.379822], [-6.619949, 53.379135], [-6.618576, 53.377762], [-6.616516, 53.377075], [-6.611023, 53.377075], [-6.608963, 53.376389], [-6.60759, 53.375015], [-6.60553, 53.374329], [-6.600037, 53.374329], [-6.597977, 53.375015], [-6.596603, 53.376389], [-6.594543, 53.377075], [-6.586304, 53.377075], [-6.584244, 53.376389], [-6.58287, 53.372269], [-6.580811, 53.371582], [-6.564331, 53.371582], [-6.562271, 53.372269], [-6.560898, 53.373642], [-6.558838, 53.374329], [-6.556091, 53.374329], [-6.554031, 53.373642], [-6.552658, 53.372269], [-6.550598, 53.371582], [-6.548538, 53.372269], [-6.547852, 53.374329], [-6.547852, 53.377075], [-6.547165, 53.379135], [-6.544418, 53.381882], [-6.542358, 53.382568], [-6.540298, 53.381882], [-6.538925, 53.380508], [-6.537552, 53.380508], [-6.536179, 53.381882], [-6.534119, 53.382568], [-6.525879, 53.382568], [-6.523819, 53.381882], [-6.522446, 53.377762], [-6.520386, 53.377075], [-6.514893, 53.377075], [-6.512833, 53.376389], [-6.511459, 53.375015], [-6.509399, 53.374329], [-6.50116, 53.374329], [-6.4991, 53.373642], [-6.497726, 53.372269], [-6.495667, 53.371582], [-6.493607, 53.372269], [-6.493607, 53.373642], [-6.497726, 53.377762], [-6.498413, 53.379822], [-6.497726, 53.381882], [-6.49498, 53.384628], [-6.49292, 53.385315], [-6.490173, 53.385315], [-6.488113, 53.384628], [-6.48674, 53.383255], [-6.48468, 53.382568], [-6.479187, 53.382568], [-6.477127, 53.381882], [-6.475754, 53.380508], [-6.471634, 53.379135], [-6.470261, 53.377762], [-6.468201, 53.377075], [-6.465454, 53.377075], [-6.463394, 53.377762], [-6.463394, 53.379135], [-6.466141, 53.381882], [-6.470261, 53.383255], [-6.473007, 53.386002], [-6.473694, 53.388062], [-6.473694, 53.396301], [-6.47438, 53.398361], [-6.4785, 53.399734], [-6.479187, 53.401794], [-6.479187, 53.404541], [-6.479874, 53.406601], [-6.481934, 53.407288], [-6.483994, 53.406601], [-6.485367, 53.402481], [-6.487427, 53.401794], [-6.495667, 53.401794], [-6.497726, 53.402481], [-6.4991, 53.406601], [-6.500473, 53.406601], [-6.501846, 53.405228], [-6.503906, 53.404541], [-6.514893, 53.404541], [-6.516953, 53.405228], [-6.517639, 53.407288], [-6.517639, 53.410034], [-6.516953, 53.412094], [-6.514893, 53.412781], [-6.512146, 53.412781], [-6.510086, 53.413467], [-6.508713, 53.414841], [-6.504593, 53.416214], [-6.50322, 53.417587], [-6.4991, 53.418961], [-6.498413, 53.421021], [-6.4991, 53.42308], [-6.50116, 53.423767], [-6.517639, 53.423767], [-6.519699, 53.424454], [-6.521072, 53.428574], [-6.525192, 53.429947], [-6.526566, 53.43132], [-6.530685, 53.432693], [-6.533432, 53.43544], [-6.534119, 53.4375], [-6.533432, 53.43956], [-6.530685, 53.442307], [-6.528625, 53.442993], [-6.525879, 53.442993], [-6.523819, 53.442307], [-6.522446, 53.440933], [-6.518326, 53.43956], [-6.516953, 53.438187], [-6.514893, 53.4375], [-6.512146, 53.4375], [-6.510086, 53.436813], [-6.508713, 53.43544], [-6.506653, 53.434753], [-6.50116, 53.434753], [-6.4991, 53.434067], [-6.497726, 53.432693], [-6.493607, 53.43132], [-6.492233, 53.429947], [-6.49086, 53.429947], [-6.489487, 53.43132], [-6.485367, 53.432693], [-6.48468, 53.434753], [-6.485367, 53.436813], [-6.489487, 53.438187], [-6.490173, 53.440247], [-6.489487, 53.442307], [-6.488113, 53.44368], [-6.488113, 53.445053], [-6.49086, 53.4478], [-6.49292, 53.448486], [-6.498413, 53.448486], [-6.500473, 53.4478], [-6.501846, 53.446426], [-6.503906, 53.44574], [-6.509399, 53.44574], [-6.511459, 53.446426], [-6.512146, 53.448486], [-6.512146, 53.451233], [-6.512833, 53.453293], [-6.514893, 53.453979], [-6.517639, 53.453979], [-6.519699, 53.454666], [-6.521072, 53.456039], [-6.525192, 53.457413], [-6.527939, 53.460159], [-6.528625, 53.462219], [-6.527939, 53.464279], [-6.525192, 53.467026], [-6.523132, 53.467712], [-6.521072, 53.467026], [-6.519699, 53.465652], [-6.517639, 53.464966], [-6.515579, 53.465652], [-6.515579, 53.467026], [-6.536179, 53.487625], [-6.536865, 53.489685], [-6.536865, 53.492432], [-6.536179, 53.494492], [-6.534119, 53.495178], [-6.528625, 53.495178], [-6.526566, 53.494492], [-6.511459, 53.479385], [-6.509399, 53.478699], [-6.506653, 53.478699], [-6.504593, 53.479385], [-6.50322, 53.480759], [-6.50116, 53.481445], [-6.4991, 53.480759], [-6.497726, 53.479385], [-6.493607, 53.478012], [-6.481247, 53.465652], [-6.479874, 53.465652], [-6.4785, 53.469772], [-6.477127, 53.471146], [-6.477127, 53.472519], [-6.4785, 53.473892], [-6.479187, 53.475952], [-6.4785, 53.478012], [-6.475754, 53.480759], [-6.473694, 53.481445], [-6.470947, 53.481445], [-6.468887, 53.480759], [-6.466141, 53.478012], [-6.465454, 53.475952], [-6.465454, 53.470459], [-6.464767, 53.468399], [-6.462021, 53.465652], [-6.457901, 53.464279], [-6.457214, 53.462219], [-6.457214, 53.459473], [-6.457901, 53.457413], [-6.459961, 53.456726], [-6.465454, 53.456726], [-6.467514, 53.456039], [-6.470261, 53.453293], [-6.470261, 53.45192], [-6.467514, 53.449173], [-6.463394, 53.4478], [-6.462021, 53.446426], [-6.459961, 53.44574], [-6.448975, 53.44574], [-6.446915, 53.446426], [-6.445541, 53.450546], [-6.443481, 53.451233], [-6.437988, 53.451233], [-6.435928, 53.450546], [-6.434555, 53.449173], [-6.430435, 53.4478], [-6.429749, 53.44574], [-6.430435, 53.44368], [-6.431808, 53.442307], [-6.431808, 53.440933], [-6.430435, 53.43956], [-6.429749, 53.4375], [-6.430435, 53.43544], [-6.434555, 53.434067], [-6.435928, 53.432693], [-6.437988, 53.432007], [-6.440735, 53.432007], [-6.442795, 53.432693], [-6.444168, 53.434067], [-6.445541, 53.434067], [-6.446915, 53.429947], [-6.451035, 53.428574], [-6.451721, 53.426514], [-6.451035, 53.424454], [-6.446915, 53.42308], [-6.445541, 53.421707], [-6.444168, 53.421707], [-6.437302, 53.428574], [-6.433182, 53.429947], [-6.431808, 53.43132], [-6.429749, 53.432007], [-6.424255, 53.432007], [-6.422195, 53.43132], [-6.418076, 53.4272], [-6.416016, 53.426514], [-6.405029, 53.426514], [-6.402969, 53.425827], [-6.401596, 53.424454], [-6.397476, 53.42308], [-6.396103, 53.421707], [-6.394043, 53.421021], [-6.391983, 53.421707], [-6.387863, 53.425827], [-6.383743, 53.4272], [-6.383057, 53.42926], [-6.383743, 53.43132], [-6.385803, 53.432007], [-6.391296, 53.432007], [-6.393356, 53.432693], [-6.39473, 53.434067], [-6.39679, 53.434753], [-6.399536, 53.434753], [-6.401596, 53.43544], [-6.402283, 53.4375], [-6.402283, 53.440247], [-6.401596, 53.442307], [-6.399536, 53.442993], [-6.383057, 53.442993], [-6.380997, 53.44368], [-6.376877, 53.4478], [-6.374817, 53.448486], [-6.369324, 53.448486], [-6.367264, 53.4478], [-6.365891, 53.446426], [-6.363831, 53.44574], [-6.361771, 53.446426], [-6.361084, 53.448486], [-6.361084, 53.451233], [-6.361771, 53.453293], [-6.363831, 53.453979], [-6.369324, 53.453979], [-6.371384, 53.454666], [-6.37207, 53.456726], [-6.37207, 53.459473], [-6.371384, 53.461533], [-6.37001, 53.462906], [-6.37001, 53.464279], [-6.371384, 53.465652], [-6.372757, 53.469772], [-6.383743, 53.480759], [-6.385803, 53.481445], [-6.38855, 53.481445], [-6.39061, 53.482132], [-6.391983, 53.483505], [-6.396103, 53.484879], [-6.397476, 53.486252], [-6.399536, 53.486938], [-6.410522, 53.486938], [-6.412582, 53.487625], [-6.413956, 53.488998], [-6.418076, 53.490372], [-6.423569, 53.495865], [-6.424255, 53.497925], [-6.424255, 53.500671], [-6.424942, 53.502731], [-6.426315, 53.504105], [-6.427002, 53.506165], [-6.427002, 53.514404], [-6.426315, 53.516464], [-6.424255, 53.517151], [-6.418762, 53.517151], [-6.416702, 53.516464], [-6.413956, 53.513718], [-6.413269, 53.511658], [-6.413269, 53.506165], [-6.412582, 53.504105], [-6.411209, 53.502731], [-6.409836, 53.498611], [-6.408463, 53.498611], [-6.407089, 53.499985], [-6.405029, 53.500671], [-6.399536, 53.500671], [-6.397476, 53.501358], [-6.39679, 53.503418], [-6.39679, 53.506165], [-6.396103, 53.508224], [-6.394043, 53.508911], [-6.38855, 53.508911], [-6.38649, 53.508224], [-6.379623, 53.501358], [-6.377563, 53.500671], [-6.37207, 53.500671], [-6.37001, 53.499985], [-6.368637, 53.498611], [-6.364517, 53.497238], [-6.363831, 53.495178], [-6.363831, 53.492432], [-6.364517, 53.490372], [-6.368637, 53.488998], [-6.368637, 53.487625], [-6.367264, 53.486252], [-6.365891, 53.482132], [-6.363144, 53.479385], [-6.361084, 53.478699], [-6.352844, 53.478699], [-6.350784, 53.478012], [-6.348038, 53.475266], [-6.348038, 53.473892], [-6.349411, 53.472519], [-6.350098, 53.470459], [-6.349411, 53.468399], [-6.348038, 53.468399], [-6.346664, 53.469772], [-6.344604, 53.470459], [-6.339111, 53.470459], [-6.337051, 53.469772], [-6.331558, 53.464279], [-6.330872, 53.462219], [-6.331558, 53.460159], [-6.335678, 53.458786], [-6.335678, 53.457413], [-6.332932, 53.454666], [-6.330872, 53.453979], [-6.319885, 53.453979], [-6.317825, 53.454666], [-6.317139, 53.456726], [-6.317139, 53.459473], [-6.316452, 53.461533], [-6.314392, 53.462219], [-6.303406, 53.462219], [-6.301346, 53.462906], [-6.299973, 53.464279], [-6.297913, 53.464966], [-6.295166, 53.464966], [-6.293106, 53.464279], [-6.290359, 53.461533], [-6.288986, 53.457413], [-6.286926, 53.456726], [-6.27594, 53.456726], [-6.27388, 53.456039], [-6.271133, 53.453293], [-6.26976, 53.449173], [-6.268387, 53.449173], [-6.267014, 53.450546], [-6.264954, 53.451233], [-6.256714, 53.451233], [-6.254654, 53.450546], [-6.253281, 53.448486], [-6.251907, 53.447113], [-6.250534, 53.4478], [-6.249161, 53.449173], [-6.247787, 53.453293], [-6.245728, 53.453979], [-6.234741, 53.453979], [-6.232681, 53.454666], [-6.228561, 53.458786], [-6.226501, 53.459473], [-6.221008, 53.459473], [-6.218948, 53.460159], [-6.218948, 53.461533], [-6.220322, 53.462906], [-6.221008, 53.464966], [-6.221008, 53.475952], [-6.220322, 53.478012], [-6.218262, 53.478699], [-6.215515, 53.478699], [-6.213455, 53.479385], [-6.212769, 53.481445], [-6.212769, 53.489685], [-6.212082, 53.491745], [-6.207962, 53.495865], [-6.207275, 53.497925], [-6.207275, 53.508911], [-6.206589, 53.510971], [-6.204529, 53.511658], [-6.199036, 53.511658], [-6.196976, 53.510971], [-6.194229, 53.508224], [-6.193542, 53.506165], [-6.193542, 53.495178], [-6.194229, 53.493118], [-6.195602, 53.491745], [-6.195602, 53.490372], [-6.194229, 53.488998], [-6.193542, 53.486938], [-6.193542, 53.484192], [-6.192856, 53.482132], [-6.191483, 53.480759], [-6.190796, 53.478699], [-6.191483, 53.476639], [-6.195602, 53.472519], [-6.196289, 53.470459], [-6.196289, 53.451233], [-6.195602, 53.449173], [-6.191483, 53.4478], [-6.188736, 53.445053], [-6.188049, 53.442993], [-6.188736, 53.440933], [-6.191483, 53.438187], [-6.193542, 53.4375], [-6.199036, 53.4375], [-6.201096, 53.436813], [-6.206589, 53.43132], [-6.206589, 53.429947], [-6.204529, 53.42926], [-6.193542, 53.42926], [-6.191483, 53.428574], [-6.190109, 53.4272], [-6.188049, 53.426514], [-6.185303, 53.426514], [-6.183243, 53.425827], [-6.182556, 53.423767], [-6.183243, 53.421707], [-6.183929, 53.420334], [-6.182556, 53.418961], [-6.17981, 53.418274], [-6.174316, 53.418274], [-6.172256, 53.417587], [-6.170883, 53.413467], [-6.166763, 53.412094], [-6.164017, 53.409348], [-6.162643, 53.405228], [-6.158524, 53.403854], [-6.155777, 53.401108], [-6.15509, 53.399048], [-6.155777, 53.396988], [-6.158524, 53.394241], [-6.162643, 53.392868], [-6.16333, 53.390808], [-6.16333, 53.388062], [-6.162643, 53.386002], [-6.160583, 53.385315], [-6.157837, 53.385315], [-6.155777, 53.386002], [-6.154404, 53.387375], [-6.152344, 53.388062], [-6.144104, 53.388062], [-6.142044, 53.387375], [-6.141357, 53.385315], [-6.141357, 53.382568], [-6.142044, 53.380508], [-6.144791, 53.377762], [-6.146851, 53.377075], [-6.149597, 53.377075], [-6.151657, 53.376389], [-6.152344, 53.374329], [-6.152344, 53.371582], [-6.15303, 53.369522], [-6.15509, 53.368835], [-6.157837, 53.368835], [-6.159897, 53.368149], [-6.16127, 53.366776], [-6.16539, 53.365402], [-6.168137, 53.362656], [-6.168137, 53.361282], [-6.166763, 53.359909], [-6.166077, 53.357849], [-6.166077, 53.355103], [-6.166763, 53.353043], [-6.168823, 53.352356], [-6.177063, 53.352356], [-6.179123, 53.353043], [-6.180496, 53.354416], [-6.182556, 53.355103], [-6.185303, 53.355103], [-6.187363, 53.354416], [-6.188049, 53.352356], [-6.188049, 53.346863], [-6.188736, 53.344803], [-6.190109, 53.34343], [-6.190796, 53.34137], [-6.190796, 53.338623], [-6.191483, 53.336563], [-6.193542, 53.335876], [-6.201782, 53.335876], [-6.203842, 53.33519], [-6.203842, 53.333817], [-6.202469, 53.332443], [-6.201096, 53.328323], [-6.199722, 53.32695], [-6.199036, 53.32489], [-6.199036, 53.319397], [-6.198349, 53.317337], [-6.195602, 53.31459], [-6.191483, 53.313217], [-6.190109, 53.311844], [-6.185989, 53.310471], [-6.185303, 53.308411], [-6.185303, 53.305664], [-6.185989, 53.303604], [-6.188049, 53.302917], [-6.190796, 53.302917], [-6.192856, 53.302231], [-6.194229, 53.298111], [-6.195602, 53.296738], [-6.196976, 53.292618], [-6.199036, 53.291931], [-6.207275, 53.291931], [-6.209335, 53.292618], [-6.210709, 53.293991], [-6.212769, 53.294678], [-6.221008, 53.294678], [-6.223068, 53.293991], [-6.224442, 53.289871], [-6.232681, 53.281631], [-6.236801, 53.280258], [-6.237488, 53.278198], [-6.236801, 53.276138], [-6.234741, 53.275452], [-6.210022, 53.275452], [-6.207962, 53.274765], [-6.206589, 53.273392], [-6.202469, 53.272018], [-6.201782, 53.269958], [-6.201782, 53.267212], [-6.202469, 53.265152], [-6.204529, 53.264465], [-6.210022, 53.264465], [-6.212082, 53.265152], [-6.213455, 53.266525], [-6.215515, 53.267212], [-6.237488, 53.267212], [-6.239548, 53.266525], [-6.240921, 53.265152], [-6.242981, 53.264465], [-6.245728, 53.264465], [-6.247787, 53.263779], [-6.249161, 53.262405], [-6.251221, 53.261719], [-6.25946, 53.261719], [-6.26152, 53.262405], [-6.262894, 53.263779], [-6.264954, 53.264465], [-6.270447, 53.264465], [-6.272507, 53.263779], [-6.27388, 53.262405], [-6.27594, 53.261719], [-6.289673, 53.261719], [-6.291733, 53.262405], [-6.293106, 53.263779], [-6.295166, 53.264465], [-6.300659, 53.264465], [-6.302719, 53.265152], [-6.304092, 53.266525], [-6.306152, 53.267212], [-6.314392, 53.267212], [-6.316452, 53.266525], [-6.316452, 53.265152], [-6.312332, 53.263779], [-6.311646, 53.261719], [-6.312332, 53.259659], [-6.315079, 53.256912], [-6.317139, 53.256226], [-6.322632, 53.256226], [-6.324692, 53.256912], [-6.328812, 53.261032], [-6.332932, 53.262405], [-6.334305, 53.263779], [-6.336365, 53.264465], [-6.347351, 53.264465], [-6.349411, 53.265152], [-6.350784, 53.266525], [-6.352158, 53.266525], [-6.353531, 53.265152], [-6.355591, 53.264465], [-6.363831, 53.264465], [-6.365891, 53.265152], [-6.366577, 53.267212], [-6.366577, 53.269958], [-6.367264, 53.272018], [-6.369324, 53.272705], [-6.377563, 53.272705], [-6.379623, 53.273392], [-6.380997, 53.277512], [-6.383057, 53.278198], [-6.385117, 53.277512], [-6.38649, 53.276138], [-6.38855, 53.275452], [-6.405029, 53.275452], [-6.407089, 53.276138], [-6.408463, 53.276825], [-6.409836, 53.275452], [-6.411209, 53.273392], [-6.413269, 53.272705], [-6.421509, 53.272705], [-6.423569, 53.273392], [-6.424942, 53.274765], [-6.426315, 53.274765], [-6.427689, 53.270645], [-6.429749, 53.269958], [-6.440735, 53.269958], [-6.442795, 53.269272], [-6.444168, 53.267899], [-6.446228, 53.267212], [-6.451721, 53.267212], [-6.453781, 53.267899], [-6.457901, 53.272018], [-6.459961, 53.273392], [-6.462708, 53.274765], [-6.465454, 53.275452], [-6.468201, 53.275452], [-6.470261, 53.274765], [-6.471634, 53.273392], [-6.475754, 53.272018], [-6.477127, 53.270645], [-6.4785, 53.270645], [-6.479874, 53.272018], [-6.481934, 53.272705], [-6.498413, 53.272705], [-6.500473, 53.272018], [-6.501846, 53.270645], [-6.503906, 53.269958], [-6.506653, 53.269958], [-6.508713, 53.269272], [-6.510086, 53.267899], [-6.514206, 53.266525], [-6.515579, 53.265152], [-6.517639, 53.264465], [-6.523132, 53.264465], [-6.525192, 53.265152], [-6.525879, 53.267212], [-6.525879, 53.269958], [-6.525192, 53.272018], [-6.521072, 53.273392], [-6.519699, 53.274765], [-6.515579, 53.276138], [-6.514206, 53.277512], [-6.510086, 53.278885], [-6.508713, 53.280258], [-6.506653, 53.280945], [-6.498413, 53.280945], [-6.496353, 53.281631], [-6.49498, 53.283005], [-6.49292, 53.283691], [-6.487427, 53.283691], [-6.485367, 53.284378], [-6.483994, 53.285751], [-6.481934, 53.286438], [-6.47644, 53.286438], [-6.47438, 53.287125], [-6.473694, 53.289185], [-6.473694, 53.291931], [-6.473007, 53.293991], [-6.470947, 53.294678], [-6.465454, 53.294678], [-6.463394, 53.293991], [-6.462021, 53.292618], [-6.459961, 53.291931], [-6.454468, 53.291931], [-6.452408, 53.292618], [-6.451035, 53.293991], [-6.446915, 53.295364], [-6.445541, 53.299484], [-6.444168, 53.300858], [-6.444168, 53.302231], [-6.446228, 53.302917], [-6.448975, 53.302917], [-6.451035, 53.303604], [-6.452408, 53.307724], [-6.454468, 53.308411], [-6.459961, 53.308411], [-6.462021, 53.307724], [-6.463394, 53.306351], [-6.465454, 53.305664], [-6.473694, 53.305664], [-6.475754, 53.306351], [-6.477127, 53.310471], [-6.479187, 53.311157], [-6.481247, 53.310471], [-6.48262, 53.309097], [-6.48468, 53.308411], [-6.490173, 53.308411], [-6.492233, 53.309097], [-6.49498, 53.311844], [-6.495667, 53.313904], [-6.49498, 53.315964], [-6.49086, 53.317337], [-6.48674, 53.321457], [-6.48468, 53.322144], [-6.473694, 53.322144], [-6.471634, 53.32283], [-6.467514, 53.32695], [-6.463394, 53.328323], [-6.463394, 53.329697], [-6.467514, 53.33107], [-6.468887, 53.332443], [-6.470947, 53.33313], [-6.47644, 53.33313], [-6.4785, 53.333817], [-6.479874, 53.33519], [-6.483994, 53.336563], [-6.485367, 53.337936], [-6.48674, 53.337936], [-6.49086, 53.333817], [-6.49498, 53.332443], [-6.495667, 53.330383], [-6.495667, 53.327637], [-6.496353, 53.325577], [-6.4991, 53.32283], [-6.50116, 53.322144], [-6.514893, 53.322144], [-6.516953, 53.321457], [-6.518326, 53.320084], [-6.520386, 53.319397], [-6.523132, 53.319397], [-6.525192, 53.320084], [-6.527939, 53.32283], [-6.528625, 53.32489], [-6.527939, 53.32695], [-6.523819, 53.33107], [-6.523132, 53.33313], [-6.523819, 53.33519], [-6.525879, 53.335876], [-6.527939, 53.33519], [-6.529312, 53.333817], [-6.531372, 53.33313], [-6.542358, 53.33313], [-6.544418, 53.333817], [-6.545105, 53.335876], [-6.545105, 53.338623], [-6.545792, 53.340683], [-6.548538, 53.34343], [-6.550598, 53.344116], [-6.553345, 53.344116], [-6.555405, 53.344803], [-6.556778, 53.348923], [-6.560898, 53.353043], [-6.562271, 53.357162], [-6.564331, 53.357849], [-6.569824, 53.357849], [-6.571884, 53.358536], [-6.573257, 53.359909], [-6.575317, 53.360596], [-6.583557, 53.360596], [-6.585617, 53.359909], [-6.58699, 53.355789], [-6.59111, 53.351669], [-6.592484, 53.347549], [-6.59523, 53.344803], [-6.59729, 53.344116], [-6.600037, 53.344116], [-6.602097, 53.344803], [-6.604843, 53.347549], [-6.60553, 53.349609], [-6.60553, 53.352356], [-6.604843, 53.354416], [-6.600723, 53.358536], [-6.600037, 53.360596], [-6.600723, 53.362656], [-6.60347, 53.365402], [-6.60553, 53.366089], [-6.61377, 53.366089], [-6.615829, 53.366776], [-6.617203, 53.368149], [-6.619263, 53.368835], [-6.624756, 53.368835], [-6.626816, 53.369522], [-6.628189, 53.370895], [-6.630249, 53.371582], [-6.635742, 53.371582], [-6.637802, 53.372269], [-6.639175, 53.373642], [-6.641235, 53.374329], [-6.643982, 53.374329], [-6.646042, 53.375015], [-6.646729, 53.377075], [-6.646729, 53.379822], [-6.646385, 53.381882], [-6.645355, 53.382568], [-6.643639, 53.382568]]], "type": "Polygon"}, "properties": {"range": {"type": "time", "value": 1500}}, "type": "Feature"}], "type": "FeatureCollection"}, "type": "GeoJSON"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specify polygons without changing the data in your question, you need to specify geometry values in dictionary form.

```
import folium

latitude = 53.372
longitude = -6.49

# Create the map
m = folium.Map(location=[latitude, longitude], zoom_start=10)

# Add a marker to the map
folium.Marker(
    [latitude, longitude]
).add_to(m)

# Add the layer
folium.GeoJson(data=value['data']['features'][0]['geometry'], name="geojson").add_to(m)
folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)

m
```

[image]

Comment: See a wealth of folium basics [here](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/tree/main/examples). Also see [this help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).